# Angular Material input | How to make 'focus' layout default

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material in my application. 
I have input fields like this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>E-mail</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Indtast e-mail">
</mat-form-field>
```

Which produces a input form:

[image]

Focusing on the input form triggers an animation that transforms the input field to the following layout:

[image]

**Question:** Is it possible to have the "focus" layout (label floating in the top left corner) activated by default?

We wish to display the placeholder text, also when a field is not focused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may set property `floatLabel` of mat-form-field to "always":

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
  <mat-label>E-mail</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Indtast e-mail">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: This only help you to show floating label but not focus element itself.